# Invert textPath letter from up to down along a path without redraw?

Tags: svg, path

I want to reverse the word compared to the line without having to redraw the line, how to do?
[image: Before]
[image: After]

/Ps: when I use transform="scale(-1,1)" it doesn't work because the line path is inverted.

[image: Before]
[image: After]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `<textPath side="...">` for that. However, it's only [supported by Firefox right now](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/textPath#Browser_compatibility).

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 100 55" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <path id="curve" fill="none" stroke="limegreen" stroke-width="1" d="M10,5 c20,60 50,50 80,10"></path>

    <text font-size="5" dy="-1">
        <textPath href="#curve" startOffset="6" side="left">Dangerous curves ahead</textPath>
    </text>
    <text font-size="5" dy="-1">
        <textPath href="#curve" startOffset="9" side="right">Dangerous curves ahead</textPath>
    </text>
</svg>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I want it to work on Chrome as well, Is there any other way?

Comment: Only by redrawing the line which you don't seem keen to do.

Comment: Oh because drawing in the opposite direction in many cases is very complicated and cumbersome. I want a workaround to help optimize my code

Comment: Have you considered using a library to automatically draw your path(s) in the opposite direction, e.g. https://github.com/Pomax/svg-path-reverse ?

Comment: Thank you Sphinxxx,, I tried it but it is having reverse curve problem like "M 114 628 C 114 702 108 708 35 708"

Answer (score 0):

If this is what you have:

```css
body{background:white;}
```

```html
<svg width="250" height="200" viewBox="0 0 250 200">
<defs>
<path id="thePath" d="M55,100 a70,40 0 1 0 0,-1 z" stroke="#FF0000" fill="transparent" stroke-width="1" ></path>
</defs>
<use xlink:href="#thePath"></use>
   <text stroke="#000000" font-size="20">
      <textPath xlink:href="#thePath" startOffset="7%">
            Some text here
      </textPath>
    </text>
</svg>
```

You can apply a transformation `transform="scale(-1,1) translate(-250,0)"` to the path like so:

```css
body{background:white;}
```

```html
<svg width="250" height="200" viewBox="0 0 250 200">
<defs>
<path id="thePath" d="M55,100 a70,40 0 1 0 0,-1 z" stroke="#FF0000" fill="transparent" stroke-width="1" transform="scale(-1,1) translate(-250,0)"></path>
</defs>
<use xlink:href="#thePath"></use>
   <text stroke="#000000" font-size="20">
      <textPath xlink:href="#thePath" startOffset="7%">
            Some text here
      </textPath>
    </text>
</svg>
```

I hope this is what you need

Comment: thank your help, but the path now is reversed direction. It's not exactly what I want